# Different setPasswordSuccessPath for different user groups

Tags: config, user-groups

I have a couple different user groups that access the front end of our site and I would like to send them to different paths depending on their user group after setting their password. Is it possible to access a user's group in general config for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

A bit heavy handed, but the only way I can think of do pull this off, would be to write a [custom plugin](https://pluginfactory.io) with it's own controller action that you change the link in the email to point to instead of Craft's [`UsersController->actionSetPassword()`](https://craftcms.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSetPassword-detail).

That method would be nearly identical to Craft's except at the end, you'd redirect based on the user groups (if any) the `$userToProcess` is a member of, instead of just the `setPasswordSuccessPath` config setting.